# How to reuse a shape in c#

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm quite new at these things, so any help would be much appreciated. Also, I've looked a lot for a solution but didn't find a specific one.
So the problem is:

I'm trying to create a program which reads a number of graphical vectorial shapes from a file, draws them and then can select one of them, modify a shape and resave the whole file.
I'm thinking that building a xaml resource file for the shapes would be a start. 
The first problem: if I define a simple shape (ellipse, rectangle, path) in xaml resources, how can I reuse it in code? A simple example would help me greatly. 
Second problem: in order to modify the shapes, I would probably have to convert all the basic shapes into path, to apply code on the points (vertex). How could I do that?
Third problem: some of the shapes are the result of combining several basic shapes. Let's say I use combined geometry several times in order to reach the final shape. But how can I get the path data of a combined geometry, in order to go to the second problem?

Comment: Why don't you search and start with something and get back with exact problem you are facing? Also check : [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

To "reuse" a shape you could define a style into `App.xaml`. For example:

Your `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp4.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="YellowEllipseWithBlackBorder" TargetType="Ellipse">

            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Yellow" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />

        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

Your `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource YellowEllipseWithBlackBorder}" />
            <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource YellowEllipseWithBlackBorder}" />
            <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource YellowEllipseWithBlackBorder}" />
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

The result:

[image: Three ellipses with the same style]

As you can see, you should just define a style for you shape and then apply it from the window with this syntax: `<Ellipse Style="{StaticResource YellowEllipseWithBlackBorder}" />`

---

If you want to do the same programmatically, you can define the style of your shape like in the previous example, then in your window's code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private StackPanel _stackPanel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _stackPanel = new StackPanel()
        {
            Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
        };

        Content = _stackPanel;

        AddEllipse();
        AddEllipse();
        AddEllipse();
    }

    public void AddEllipse()
    {
        var ellipse = new Ellipse()
        {
            Style = FindResource("YellowEllipseWithBlackBorder") as Style
        };

        _stackPanel.Children.Add(ellipse);
    }
}
```

---

To draw a custom shape, you could use the `Polygon` control, in which you can define the points of your shape, for example:

```
    public void AddPolygon()
    {
        var polygon = new Polygon()
        {
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
            StrokeThickness = 2.0
        };

        polygon.Points.Add(new Point(0, 0));
        polygon.Points.Add(new Point(10, 0));
        polygon.Points.Add(new Point(5, -10));

        _stackPanel.Children.Add(polygon);
    }
```

The result:

[image: Polygon]

---

To draw some curved lines, you could use the `Path` control with `BezierSegment`, for example:

```
    public void AddPath()
    {
        var canvas = new Canvas();

        var path = new Path()
        {
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
            StrokeThickness = 2.0
        };

        var geometry = new PathGeometry();
        geometry.Figures.Add(new PathFigure(
            new Point(0, 0),
            new List<BezierSegment>()
            {
                new BezierSegment(
                    new Point(0, 0),
                    new Point(100, 0),
                    new Point(50, -100),
                    true)
            },
            false));

        path.Data = geometry;
        canvas.Children.Add(path);
        _stackPanel.Children.Add(canvas);
    }
```

[image: Path with BezierSegment]

Comment: Thank you for the example. However, I was trying to reuse the ellipse from the code, not from xaml window, I don't know if it's possible. More than that, an example of what I would want to do is take that ellipse, convert it to a path, so in code I can move a single point of the ellipse, so in the end becomes an irregular shape.